# Error when running TensorFlow image retraining tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very basic question about TensorFlow. I'm following the ["TensorFlow for Poets" tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4), and I'm stuck at the image retraining, when I try to run this command:

```
# python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
```

I got an error: `"--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks: No such file or directory"`

I have installed TensorFlow using Anaconda installation, and I didn't install Docker as it was recommended in the codelab tutorial. So my question is what am I doing wrong? Is it necessary to install Docker Toolbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you have pasted the exact command from your question (and from the original tutorial) into the shell, and the `#` at the beginning was interpreted as a comment, and it's trying to execute the second line as a command.

If you paste the command **without the `#`**, it should work:

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
```

This looks like a bug in the tutorial—the second command on the same page doesn't have the `#`—so I've filed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4444) to get this fixed.

Comment: So I have tried your solution, and now I get: "can't open file 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py'". Does it mean that I didn't install tensorFlow in a proper way? Should I try to install Docker Toolbox also?

Comment: The tutorial assumes that you've installed the Docker image, and sets up files in the appropriate locations. However, this command should work if you run it from the root of the TensorFlow git repository (and you have downloaded the images to `/tf_files/flower_photos`).

Comment: I just have downloaded Docker Toolbox as it described in tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2 I got "root@....", and when I'm trying to use command "import tensorflow as tf" I got a message: "bash: import: command not found".

Comment: I have downloaded images to /tf_files/flower_photos. How to run command from the root of the TensorFlow git repository?

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf` is a Python statement, not a command that you can type at a (presumably bash) command-line prompt. Make sure you run `python` before typing that command.

Comment: To run from the root of the git repository, you first need to run the command `cd $PATH_TO_REPOSITORY`, where `$PATH_TO_REPOSITORY` is the directory where you cloned the TensorFlow git repository.